# Display or Cycle 3 divs at a time

Tags: jquery

I have a section on my page that is to show 3 divs at a time, although there may be additional divs hidden.

By clicking on a "more" button, the next 3 divs will fade in, and the previous ones will fade out.

So if we have 6 divs, the first 3 are displayed, clicking on the More button, divs 4-6 will be displayed.

If possible the 3 divs should be shown at all time.

So for example if we have 5 divs, then when you click on the More button, divs 3-5 are displayed.

I know there is a jquery plugin called jCarousel that can do this, but just wondering if it is possible without a plugin because I am building a responsive website and the  carousel plugin uses fixed size DIVs.

EDIT:
HTML:

```
<a class="more" href="#">More</a>

<div id="container">
    <div class="item"><div>One</div><div>some more text</div></div>
    <div class="item"><div>Two</div><div>some more text</div></div>
    <div class="item"><div>Three</div><div>some more text</div></div>
    <div class="item"><div>Four</div><div>some more text</div></div>
    <div class="item"><div>Five</div><div>some more text</div></div>
    <div class="item"><div>Six</div><div>some more text</div></div>

</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#container .item").slice(0,3).show();

$(".more").click(function(event) { 
  var $currElements = $("#container .item:visible");
  var $nextElements = $("#container .item:hidden");


    $currElements.hide();
    $nextElements.show();

    event.preventDefault();

});
```

This is what I currently have: http://jsfiddle.net/Wnp5J/

Just wondering now if it is possible to cycle back to the first 3 items when you click on the button again.

Also, if possible, to always display 3 items.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Good luck working on it!

Comment: Of course, all a plugin is, is a piece of code written by somebody else to make other people's lives easier.

Comment: The only reason I am asking a non-plugin solution, is because I am using this on a responsive website, and jCarousel plugin adds a fixed width to each of my divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jsFiddle: [Paging](http://jsfiddle.net/Wnp5J/2/) & [transitions](http://jsfiddle.net/Wnp5J/5/)

jsFiddle: [Paging](http://jsfiddle.net/Wnp5J/7/) (page always full)

jsFiddle: [Carousel](http://jsfiddle.net/Wnp5J/6/)

Works for any number of elements.

**Paging:**

```
$("#container .item").slice(0,3).show();

$(".more").click(function() {

    var items = $('#container .item:visible').hide().last();

    var nextItems = items.nextAll().slice(0, 3);

    if (nextItems.length === 0) {
        nextItems = $("#container .item").slice(0, 3);
    }

    nextItems.show();
});
```

**Paging w/Transitions:**

```
$("#container .item").slice(0,3).show();

$(".more").click(function() {

    var items = $('#container .item:visible');

    var nextItems = items.last().nextAll().slice(0, 3);

    if (nextItems.length === 0) {
        nextItems = $("#container .item").slice(0, 3);
    }

    items.stop().hide(500, function() {
        nextItems.show(500);
    });
});
```

**Paging (page always full):**

```
$("#container .item").slice(0,3).show();

$(".more").click(function() {

    var items = $('#container .item:visible').hide().last();

    var nextItems = items.nextAll().slice(0, 3);

    if (nextItems.length === 1) {
        nextItems = $("#container .item").slice(-3);
    }

    if (nextItems.length === 0) {
        nextItems = $("#container .item").slice(0, 3);
    }

    nextItems.show();
});
```

**Carousel:**

```
$(function() {

    var container = $('#container');
    var cycle = function() {
        container.find('.item')
            .hide()
            .slice(0, 3)
            .appendTo(container)
            .show();
    }

    $(".more").click(function() {
        cycle();
    });

    cycle();
});
```

Comment: Thank you Christopher. I like your Paging solution. Do you know if it is possible to always have 3 displayed?

Comment: If you're paginating, you'll display 3 items at a time, assuming you have a multiple of three items total. Aka: [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]. If you have a non-multiple of three, you'll end up with something like [[1,2,3],[4,5]]. Are you wanting something different? Aka: [[1,2,3],[3,4,5]] (Paginated, page always full), or [[1,2,3],[4,5,1]] (Carousel)?

Comment: Both solutions seem like they could work. The Carousel may have better advantages.

Answer (score 0):

I admit that I'm a bit confused by your request. Here's one idea.

```
$(".more").click(function (event) {
  $("#container .item").slice(3, 99).toggle();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Wnp5J/4/